# Excel macro/ keep last duplicate

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have an extensive worksheet with company entries with each 5 attributes.

I’m looking to have the last update of each company. Thus, in the case of duplicates (when a company appears several times) to keep the latest entry.

The company name (which is the identifier) is in column A. Table has titles (row 6) and actual table start in row 7.

I’ve looked at the built in remove duplicates. But that leaves me with the first entry.

I’m really inexperienced when it comes to applying macros. Any help much appreciated

Tried built in remove duplicate and some commonly available macros. But none of them have worked so far

type here

Comment: Does your table have a date on which you can sort descending?

Comment: Thanks for asking. Yes I do have a date for sorting

Comment: Then sort it descending then use remove duplicates.  It will leave the top one which will be the latest date.

Comment: What does *"with each 5 attributes"* mean? Are you removing duplicates based on two columns? What is the other column? What does "*to keep the latest entry*" mean? To keep the bottom-most entry or do we have to check a date column? Please share a screenshot of your data and the *useless RemoveDuplicates code* to make the whole thing more understandable. Also, share if the data are only values or if there are formats and formulas to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub lastDublicate()
searchCol = "A" ' column for search
c = 7 ' first row for search
i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last row for search
searchEnd = ":" & searchCol & i 'last cell for search
searchValue = Range(searchCol & c).Value
arr = Range(searchCol & c + 1 & searchEnd).Value

Do While searchValue
    IsInArray = IsNumeric(Application.Match(searchValue, arr, 0))
    If IsInArray Then
        Rows(Range(searchCol & c).Row).Delete
    Else
        c = c + 1
    End If
    searchValue = Range(searchCol & c).Value
    arr = Range(searchCol & c + 1 & searchEnd).Value
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).